# NodeJS run-series - what does it actually do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm missing the point of this module '[run-series](https://github.com/feross/run-series)'. The homepage says that it:

> Run the functions in the tasks array in series, each one running once the previous function has completed.

How is that different to just running this:

```
foo();
bar();
```

I briefly thought it might be for functions which execute asynchronous stuff, but if that were the case I'd have thought it would mention it, especially since it would then not really be asynchronous anymore? Unless it is doing the same thing as Fibers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's designed for asynchronous operations that run asynchronously in the background and signal their completion with a callback.  It is similar to `async.series()` or `Promise.mapSeries()` in other third party libraries.

Running the functions as you show would have both async operations running in flight at the same time, not one after the other.  For async operations, your example would start the second async operation after the first one had been started, but would not wait until the first one had completed.

From the documentation:

> This module is basically equavalent to async.series, but it's handy to
>   just have the functions you need instead of the kitchen sink.

It works only with functions that take a callback and will call that callback when their operation is done which is the scheme for asynchronous operations.  There is certainly no need to do any of this for synchronous operations.